# How to know the URL of my server in Apache?

Tags: apache, url

I have downloaded the WampServer and I trying to upload an image. I have search a lot but I don't know how to know my URL. The code is from http://stunningco.de/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/. This give me the Log

```
String urlServer = "http://localhost/handle_upload.php";
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
URL url = new URL(urlServer);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try
{
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(mFileName)    );

    URL url = new URL(urlServer);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    // Allow Inputs &amp; Outputs.
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setUseCaches(false);

    // Set HTTP method to POST.
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

    outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // Read file
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    // Responses from the server (code and message)
    serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    //serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

    fileInputStream.close();
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
            "Count="+count, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.e("executeMultiPartRequest", "prepare() failed");
    //Exception handling
}
```

Comment: What are you talking about? `know my URL` If you are using WAMP it's probably `http://localhost`

Comment: Ok this is what i have *http://localhost/handle_upload.php* ,so the problem is not there? Is there a form to verify if is that? Thanks